# Herkunft 'schlauchen'

Tags: etymology

Das Verb 'schlauchen' ist lustig.

Wenn etwas einen schlaucht, dann ist es anstrengend und ermüdend.

Die Herkunft von so schönen Redewendungen wie "auf dem Schlauch stehen" ist einleuchtend. Mir erschließt sich aber nicht, woher das Verb 'schlauchen' kommt. DWDS und auch google haben mich bisher auch nicht über eine reine Begriffserklärung weitergebracht. Woher kommt das Wort und seine Bedeutung?

Comment: Hier gibt es Quellen: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schlauchen (Habe ich gerade schnell gefunden mit Google.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laut [Grimm](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#1) hat das Verb *schlauchen* verschiedene, voneinander unabhängige Ursprünge:

1. Gemeinsame Herkunft mit *schlucken* aus dem indogermanischen Stamm *slug* (der *Schlauch* ist das Werkzeug, mit dem man schluckt)
2. Die wörtliche Herkunft - "mit einem Schlauch versehen", "aus dem Schlauch laufen lassen" - hier aber nicht gefragt
3. Eine Verballhornung von *schleichen*, schleppend gehen

Der Duden weiß dazu "aus der Soldatensprache: weich machen wie einen Schlauch".

Für dein Beispiel vermute ich (1) (wahrscheinlicher) oder (3) - Es ist naheliegend, dass man, wenn man etwas "zu schlucken" hatte, "geschlaucht" sein kann. Die Duden-Erklärung passt dazu und ist ebenfalls naheliegend.

Comment: Dein Post fängt so gut an! "Wenn etwas einen schlaucht" müsste aber, Deinen Quellen nach "Wenn etwas einen schluckt" bedeuten, nicht "man hatte etwas zu schlucken". Das Fazit ist misslungen.

Comment: @userunknown falls nicht der Lautwandel deine besorgnis ist, vgl. *das kotzt mich an*, wie *es dürstet mich*, *mir ist kalt*, *mich friert's* usw., zudem Ellipse wenn man geschlaucht ist plausibel

Comment: @Vectory: Wäre Lautwandel mein Thema hätte ich es erwähnt. "Das kotzt mich an" würde ich näher untersuchen, wenn "Das schlaucht mich an" irgendwas bedeutete. "Es dürstet mich" oder "Mich dürstet nach Bier" u.ä. - was hat das mit schlucken zu tun? "Mich schluckt", "Es schluckt mich"? Dagegen "Lässt mich schlucken", analog wäre vielleicht "Lässt mich husten" aber nicht "schlaucht mich/schluckt mich". Keine Ähnlichkeit, nicht plausibel. Was soll die Ellipse sein?

Comment: Siehe übrigens *darben* neben *dürfen* etc. Das erschließt sich mir ebenso wenig.

Comment: Ich glaube eher dass hier *schleifen* naheliegt, wie man von Burgen sagt. Sowie man englisch *sleave* zu bspw. Ärmeln, *loop* anstelle *Schlaufe, Schleife*, und *hose* von Schläuchen sagt, erschließt sich das fast von selbst. S.a. *schlürfen* von geräuschvollem Trinken wie auch von einer Gangart, bei der die Schuh auf dem Boden schleifen, wenn man schleppend vorangeht, sicherlich laut malerisch; *jemanden abschleppen* oder *wegschleifen*. "Das schleift bei dir!" hat man vielleicht schon mal gehört; *schlauchen* für *schleifen* zwar nicht. Vgl. *grinds my gears, on the grind*; *slow, slough*

Comment: Und bzgl. "weich machen wie einen Schlauch" hätten wa noch *schlaff*, *einschlafen*, oder engl. *slack, sluggish* https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/is-einschlafen-of-limp-limbs-akin-to-schlaff-limp *schlucken* muss(!?) also vom *Schluckspecht* kommen, vgl. *ein Schlückchen*, auch *edler Tropfen*

Comment: @user-unknown hier ein reales Beispiel, Flensburger Petuh: "Ich schwindel so leicht." Fernsehdeutsch: "Mir ist so schnell schwindelig." (Wikipedia: Petuh) Für den Vergleich muss man vielleicht *ge-schlaucht, ich bin geschlaucht* unterstellen. Ich denke, das hat man schon mal gehört.