# Streusel-Schnecke oder Schneck?

Tags: etymology, idiom, history, regional

Backt mich auf bitte, eine Streuselschnecke hat ja keine Schneckenform. Ähnliche Snacks, die eine derartige Form doch aufweisen, möchten wohl augenfällige Wortspiele sein.

Was war zuerst, die Schnecke oder der Schnack zwischendurch?

***PS***:

1. Wegen einiger Aufregung sei auf folgende Fotografien verwiesen

## [image: 1. am Bahnhof Ostkreuz, Berlin]

## [image: 2. Ostbahnhof, Berlin]

## [image: 3. Bäckereifachverkäufer in Magdeburg]

[image: Streuselschnecke]

- Ausweislich der Beschilderung in den Auslagen diverse Verkaufsstellen (1. und 2. Berlin, 3. Magdeburg) wird unter der bezeichneten "Streuselschnecke" zumindest hier das dargstellte Gebäck geführt, welches aus einem schweren Teigfladen mit Zuckerstreuseln besteht.
- Daneben im Bild (1. und 2.) liegt ein der Form ähnlich anmutendes, einmal Streuselschnecke mit Johannisbeeren genanntes Stück, ein ander mal *Johannisbeertaler*. Ferner ist sogar von Mohnschnecke die Rede (1.).
- In einem Supermarkt, dem der Bäcker (zu 3.) vorgelagert ist, führt die französisch-stämmige Handelskette wiederum *Streuseltaler*. In derselben Straße führte ein weiteres Geschäft Streuseltaler neben gefülltem Streusel. Laut Fachverkauf aus dem Umland spreche man ggf. schlicht von *Streusel*.

  - Das war mir bisher tatsächlich noch nie so bewusst aufgefallen. Wenn ich eine Streuselschnecke bestelle versteht man mich anders als bei der *Schrippe* in der Regel sofort. Richtung Dortmund übrigens nicht mehr so gut.
  - Ob das Wort daneben etwas anderes bezeichnen kann bzw. das Gebäck auch anders genannt werden mag, darf fürs erste dahinstehen.
- Dagegen sind die tatsächlich gerollten Teile im Bild entweder unbeschriftet (Rosinenschnecke (2.), Mohnschnecke (2. u. 3.)) oder als Hefestück (2.) noch zu erkennen, welche zufällig aus leichterem Teig bestehen. Für die "Berliner Brezel" (1.) bitte ich vorab schon mal um Entschuldigung.
- Ferner ist ein *Sandtaler* entgegen dem Streusel tatsächlich flach: [image: Mürbeteig Sandtaler]

2. Der Vermutung nach, das Wort könne mit *Schnack* sowie En. *Snack* zusammen gehangen haben, sei wiederum auf En. [bread roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_roll) verwiesen, das ist einfach ein Brötchen. Da ist ebenfalls kein Aufrollen zu erkennen. Es ist nicht unbedingt notwendig, allerdings scheint es wegen des Namens doch plausibel, von der gewundenen Form als Vorläufer auszugehen. Im Gegenteil ist der Fladen jedoch einfacher.

> **Schnecke** f. Name eines sehr langsam kriechenden Weichtieres, von dem viele Arten mit einem Gehäuse ausgestattet sind, ahd. sneggo m. (9. Jh.), mhd. snecke, snegge m. (vgl. obd. Schneck m.), mnd. snigge, snicke f. m., mengl. snegge führen mit intensiver Doppelkonsonanz auf germ. *sneg-, snek-.

> **schnacken** Vb. ‘plaudern, schwatzen’, ein nd. Wort, seit dem 16. Jh. auch in der Literatursprache. Mnd. snacken ‘sprechen, plaudern, schwatzen’, mnl. snacken ‘nach etw. haschen, schwatzen’, nl. snakken ‘schnappen, verlangen, sich sehnen’ stehen mit expressiver Konsonantendopplung neben nl. snaken ‘gierig nach etw. verlangen’, anord. snaka ‘schnüffeln, wittern’, isl. snaka ‘herumschnüffeln’. Lautmalende Bildungen mit anlautendem germ. sn- [...]

> **Snack** m. [...] gleichbed. engl. snack, älter auch ‘(An)teil, Schluck’, (mundartlich) to snack ‘beißen, schnappen’, entlehnt aus mnl. snacken ‘gierig zuschnappen, -beißen’. Weiteres ungewiß. [https://DWDS.de/wb/etym-wb/]

- Die besagten *lautmalenden Bildungen mit anlautendem germ. sn-* sind unterdessen bemerkenswert weil die Fülle an Formen schwer zu greifen ist und dabei auch gar nicht auf sn- zu beschränken ist (vgl. i. *slug* "Schnecke", ii. *snap, nap, nab* "schnappen", iii. *snare* "schnarren" beside *knarren, ratschen*, or as recently discussed *schlauchen* and *schlucken* [[@tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69569/35977)]; at least *ratschen* is synonym to *schnacken*).

3. Der ähnlichen Form wegen sei auf den Namen *Strietzel* verwiesen, zudem Abarten ggf. der Folksetymologie unterliegen (etwa. Cz. *kolo* [[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challah),[2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bread_rolls)]).

Comment: Eine Streuselschnecke hat die Rundungen und Windungen eines Schneckenhauses; oder?

Comment: Ich hab grad eine verknuspert und wie jede andere Streuselschnecke im Norden, wo immerhin die Worte *Snack* und *Schnack* zu verorten sind, ist das halt ein rundes Hafergebäck mit Streuseln ohne die für ein Schneckenhaus typische Windung. Rosinenschnecken dagegen haben auch hier ein doch eher unnötiges Gewinde, dabei sind Rosinen sicherlich eher west-rheinisch bis südlich, Sultaninen wie der Name vermuten ließe sogar äußerst südländisch, falls nicht ursprünglich zur Konservierung gessalzen.

Comment: Wenn das Gebäck schneckenhausförmig ist, dann handelt es sich wohl nicht um ein Wortspiel, sondern um eine Metapher. Und die eigentliche Frage ist jetzt, was zuerst war, der Begriff Schnecke oder Schnack? Oder Schneck, wie in der Überschrift?

Comment: Die Frage ist dementsprechend, ob die schneckige Schnecke, nicht das Tier, weiter zurück geht als die Wortgruppe um Schnacken, die Hochdeutsch theoretisch auch früher gehabt haben kann, wenn nicht aus des Niederdeutsch Kreuzeinfluss.

Answer (score 3):

Grundsätzlich kann man in erster Näherung annehmen, dass Gebäckstücke, die „Schnecke“ heißen, spiralförmig sind. Meist hergestellt indem eine Teigplatte ausgerollt, mit einer Art Belag bestrichen oder bestreut, dann aufgerollt und diese Rolle dann in Streifen geschnitten wird. Im Anschnitt ergibt sich die namensgebende Schnecke oder Spirale - siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schnecke):

> kleines, rundes Gebäck mit Zuckerguss, bei dem der Teig spiralig zusammengerollt ist

Die Füllung findet sich i.A. im Namen wieder - Zimtschnecke, Mohnschnecke, Nussschnecke etc.

- Es gibt durchaus Streuselschnecken, die namensgemäß gerollt sind, zum Beispiel im Angebot einer lokalen [Bäckerei](https://www.sehne.de/). [image] ([1](https://de.restaurantguru.com/Sehne-Backwaren-Renningen-3#gallery))
- Die [Streuselschnecke „ohne Spirale“](https://amp.kochbar.de/rezept/435283/Backen-Streuselschnecken.html) beruht meiner Einschätzung nach auf einer Vereinfachung der Herstellung nach dem Motto „unter einer großzügigen Schicht Streusel sieht man eh‘ nix“. Diese Version findet man auch unter dem Begriff „Streuseltaler“, der meiner Meinung nach weniger irreführend ist, z.B. [hier](https://kamps.de/produkte/feingebaeck-streuseltaler).

Der Begriff Snack“ für eine kleine Mahlzeit zwischendurch, einen Imbiss, ist erst seit einigen Jahrzehnten gebräuchlich, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Snack) nennt das 20. Jahrhundert, allerdings ohne Angabe des Jahrzehnts. Gebäckstücke namens „Schnecke” finde ich bereits in meinem Kochbuch von 1928 (und das ist lediglich die älteste Quelle auf die ich direkt zugreifen kann, ich würde annehmen, dass sich der Begriff wesentlich früher belegen lässt).

Comment: Der entscheidende Abschnitt als offensichtlich hingestellt, was Schnecke hieße werde gerollt und auch umgekehrt, ist mit einem Bild jüngeren Datums leider nicht ausreichend belegt. Hier scheint ein Missverständnis vorzuliegen, denn die Einleitung begründet zuerst meinen Gedankenansatz, der nicht in Frage steht. Zwar dachte ich, die Dingers werden wie Brezeln aus schlingen gemacht. Die Tatsache im Gegenteil tut der Frage aber keinen Abbruch. Dieser Versuch einer Antwort geht darüber leider nicht hinaus und verkennt das Problem. *snacken* ist im Deutschen durchaus älter.

Comment: Sofern das Wort ein *Zahlungsmittel* heißt, ist *Taler* durchaus auch mit *erzählen* vergleichbar, wenngleich als Ursprung zumeist der berüchtigte Joachimsthaler angeführt wird, bleibt fraglich, ob das Toponym auf Berg und Tal gemünzt ist. *Münze* kommt ja auch nicht von *Münster*. Der *Pfennig* (auch als Toponym?) wurde schon mal mit *Pfanne* verglichen, womit es in einem ungewissen Sinne etwa als *Becken* zu verstehen dem *Tal* durchaus nahe käme, zumal nach Lat. *tegula* "tile", *Ziegel* wie *Tiegel*, Fr. *tuile*, Slovak. *tehla* etc. noch entfernt an die Backware erinnert.

Answer (score 0):

Ein Schnack ist eine Unterhaltung. Ein Snack ist essbar und als deutsches Wort eher neueren Ursprungs, da dem Englischen entlehnt. Eine Streuselschnecke könnte ein Snack sein und hat vermutlich ursprünglich, zumindest manchmal schon eine Windung - und heißt deshalb so weil in Form entfernt angelehnt an eine Gehäuseschnecke. Schnecken sind als Spezies älter als Streuselschnecken. Ob Schnacken unter Menschen(affen) älter ist oder Schnecken älter sind, vermag ein Biologe zu sagen - vermutlich die Schnecken, oder zumindest als die Fähigkeit von Menschen(affen) einen Schnack zu halten.

Comment: Dennoch, oder genau trotzdem, diese Antwort scheint mir in Stil und Form dem der Frage gut zu entsprechen.

Comment: Ja genau, diese Antwort ist *fragwürdig*, wenn du das meinst

Answer (score -1):

Vielleicht liegt das Problem bei den falschen Voraussetzungen:

> eine Streuselschnecke hat ja keine Schneckenform.

Was ist denn eine "Schneckenform"? Meinst Du die Form einer *Schnecke* oder doch die Form einen *Scheckenhauses*? Schnecken können durchaus so aussehen wie eine Streuselschnecke, denn Schnecken haben nicht notwendigerweise ein (spiralig gewundenes) Haus.

Als Beispiel die Gattung *ferrissia* ([Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrissia) oder die Überfamilie der "Teichnapfschnecken" (*Acroloxoidea*, [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichnapfschnecken)), die ähnlich wie Muscheln aussehen.

Comment: Wenn der Begriff „Schnecke“ in übertragener Form benutzt wird, geht es entweder um Geschwindigkeit (die Schnecke im Straßenverkehr) oder die gewundene Form des Gehäuses - von Bauteil bis Gebäck. Nacktschnecken sind z.B. eher walzenförmig, dennoch werden für solche Formen andere Analogien gewählt - siehe „ Bubespitzle“ for example.

Comment: Ich entnehme dem, daß die überwiegende Mehrzahl aller Schneckenarten nicht schneckenförmig sind.

Comment: … ein Fakt, den die Sprache sorglos ignoriert wenn es um Bedeutungsübertragung geht.

Comment: @Stephie: und dafür hast du sicher auch einen Beleg, oder? Zum Beispiel spielt die Redewendung "sich in sein Schneckenhaus zurückziehen" ausschließlich auf die Gewundenheit des Hauses und/oder die Langsamkeit der Schnecke an, nicht wahr? Soviel zu deinem Kommentar "geht es entweder um Geschwindigkeit oder die gewundene Form".